# Background image isn't scrolling?

Tags: css, scroll, background-image

My background image isn't scrolling up and down, or else it is scrolling down too far.  I want it to scroll down to the bottom of the background image and then stop.

```
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
.noWhiteSpace {
margin-left:0;
margin-right:0;
margin-top:0;
background-color:#F4F7E3;
background-image:url('/front_page.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100%;
height:180%;
}
.words {
font-family:Madelinette;
text-align:center;
margin-left:25%;
margin-top:10%;
}
#lineOne {
color:#5f4e2b;
font-size:5em;
}
#lineTwo {
color:#629040;
font-size:4em;
padding-bottom:2%;
}
#otherLines {
color:#952221;
font-size:2em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body class='noWhiteSpace'>
<div class='words'>
<div id='lineOne'>Crafters &nbsp;Resale</div>
<div id='lineTwo'>blah</div>
<div id='otherLines'>blah<br>blah<br>blah<br>blah<br>blah</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `background-attachment: scroll` means that it scrolls with the content. If your content is not long enough, there will be no scrolling. It's not independent of the container.

Comment: post relevant code of your problem, it will help us to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

background-attachment: scroll is by default you don't need to specify that. Your image is not scrolling because your body don't have enough height try giving height explicitly in css or just add some more content in your body.

Hope this will help you but if you were asking something different please elaborate it.

Comment: I tried adding a height of 100% and that stretched/smushed the image.  How can I set the height in a way that will work for different screen sizes?  I also tried adding some text right before the end of the body and that didn't change the way the page looks.

Answer (score 0):

height of 100% means your whole content will be displayed but dude background-image don't get count in the content(if you add img tag then it will be counted). So you need to give the height same as that of your img in px. For eg.

```
.noWhiteSpace {
    height: 2222px; /* I think that was your background-img height */
    /* your other styling .... */
}
```